# How to migrate an add-in to Office 2013?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-2010, office-2013

I've found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp142161%28v=office.15%29), the bottom line of which foretells that what I've been using this far to create Office add-ins (i.e. good, old, nice C# code) is to be entirely exchanged for JavaScript.

For instance, we've got a solution that puts a set of buttons on the ribbon and communicates with a CRM server to add data (one in Outlook and one in Word). Will those need to be rewritten as a whole?!

I wish to use VSTO if possible (AddInExpress has been said not to be reliable, apparently). Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but I don't think C# or VB.NET has been abandoned in this context.  Here's a recent blog from the VSTO team with a screen-shot of an Addin solution using C#, and another screen-shot using VB.NET project templates.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx